# systemd does not stop Docker Application Container Engine

Tags: 18.04, systemd, docker

**Issue:** Every time I reboot or shut down, I have to wait an arbitrary number of minutes due to systemd when it tries to stop the Docker Application Engine.

**System:**

- xubuntu 18.04 on a Lenovo Thinkpad x260
- `DISTRIB_ID=Ubuntu
  DISTRIB_RELEASE=18.04
  DISTRIB_CODENAME=bionic
  DISTRIB_DESCRIPTION="Ubuntu 18.04.1 LTS"`
- docker installed via apt
- `docker --version` gives `Docker version 18.09.0-ce-tp5, build 9eb3d36`
- `systemctl --version` gives `systemd 237
  +PAM +AUDIT +SELINUX +IMA +APPARMOR +SMACK +SYSVINIT +UTMP +LIBCRYPTSETUP +GCRYPT +GNUTLS +ACL +XZ +LZ4 +SECCOMP +BLKID +ELFUTILS +KMOD -IDN2 +IDN -PCRE2 default-hierarchy=hybrid`
- No containers are running at the time of the shutdown request. I explicitly stopped and removed them beforehand (`docker container ls --all` shows nothing).

**Behavior:** After I click the "Shutdown" or "Reboot" button, the GUI shuts down and shows the xubuntu logo with a spinning icon. Pressing *Esc*, I am welcomed by the systemd service status screen. Only 2-3 lines occur (as can be seen in the photo below), then I have to wait arbitrarily long (values between 1min and 25min actively observed). Because I cannot ensure that systemd will terminate any time soon, I usually use the hardware button to shutdown my machine. This issue occurs since I have docker installed on my system.

[image: photograph of systemd messages]

```
[ OK ] Started Show Plymouth Power Off Screen.
[   *] A stop job is running for Docker Application Container Engine (14s / no limit)[ OK ] Started Show Plymouth Power Off Screen.
[ ** ] A stop job is running for Docker Application Container Engine (24min 27s / no limit)
```

**Question:** how can I make docker stop gracefully?

Comment: Have you solved it?

Comment: @Sergey Sadly no. I am still suffering from this issue.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I occasionally have this issue and I'm not sure why docker has hung.  But what I have found is that the timeout is explicitly set to unlimited in the service file deployed by docker-ce:

```
$ grep Timeout /lib/systemd/system/docker.service 
TimeoutSec=0
```

To avoid this hanging for extended periods I set the `TimeoutStopSec` parameter in an override:

```
$ sudo systemctl edit docker.service
```

Add the following lines:

```
[Service]
TimeoutStopSec=300
```

Then reload:

```
$ sudo systemctl daemon-reload
```

Comment: I reinstalled my system with Ubuntu 20.04 and therefore cannot confirm the solution. However, I have high confidence that this solution works and thus, I am going to accept it. Thanks!